# onActivityResult requestcode Facebook SDK

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I'm building an `Android` app which uses the `Facebook SDK`so people can share URL's. I'm using onActivityResult for multiple things in my activity, so I'm using a switch on `requestCode` so that I know what to do with every activityresult. How do I get the proper requestCode when for example I cancel sharing a facebook post? This is my code at the moment:

```
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1: 
        ... doing some not-facebook-related stuff here
        case 2:
        ... doing some other not-facebook-related stuff here


//      case ??? : 
//      callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
```

So what is the right requestCode and how do I get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a sharedialog instead

```
new ShareDialog(this).registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Sharer.Result result) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {

            }
        });
```

When you cancel share you get to onCancel callback.
Also uncomment this

```
callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
```

from onActivityResult method.

Comment: I used to have it uncommented, but let me explain. In the same activity I have camera and gallery functionality, and when I put the callbackManager.onActivityResult uncommented there, and I cancel for example taking a picture, the app crashes because the resultcode for the camera cancel gets passed in the facebook callbackManager. Does that make sense? That makes me think, is it even nessecary to have facebook callbackManager in onActivityResult or can I just leave that away since it's used in the ShareDialog anyways?

Comment: I am sure it will be necessary to have callbackManager in onActivityResult. Here is the documentation : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android

Comment: For camera and gallery functionality what you can do is print there success and failure resultCode and handle them in switch case statements and in default case put 'callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);'

Answer (score 3):

This is what I've used in a similar case:

```
    if (requestCode == CallbackManagerImpl.RequestCodeOffset.Login.toRequestCode()) {
        // call callbackManager
    }
```

You can also set the offset of requestcodes used by FacebookSdk:

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext(), 10000);
```

By the way, I have found this looking through the source code, so I'm not sure how "safe" this option is as `CallbackManagerImpl.RequestCodeOffset.Login.toRequestCode()` is not a "public" documented method.

Comment: This question is from more than half a year ago and already solved for a looong time (I honestly can't even remember I posted this). But thanks anyways!